# org.json.JSONException: No value for opening_hours ,how to handle this type of error

Tags: json, parsing, android-volley

logcat screenshot
[image: logcat screenshot]

**after parsing json if there is no value for opening_hours nothing is  displaying how to handle that please help me.
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJoTjQ-EC_wjsRjC-0kVQOIg0&key=API_KEY"   **

> I did all techniques but not got success in that please help me to resolve this error

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView image_details, open, close;
    private TextView text_mobile, openNow;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    String place_id, img_url, mobile, open_now;
    ArrayList<DetailsPojo> mDetailsList;
    private Context mContext;
    LinearLayout openingLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        findViewByIds();
        mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //if (getIntent().hasExtra("PLACE_ID"))
        place_id = intent.getStringExtra("PLACE_ID");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Place ID :" + place_id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        parseJson();

    }

    private void parseJson() {
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + place_id + "&key=" + KEY;
        Log.d("DetailedURL",url);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject resultObject = response.getJSONObject("result");
                    mobile = resultObject.optString("formatted_phone_number", "not available");

                    if (resultObject.has("formatted_phone_number")) {

                        text_mobile.setText(mobile);
                    } else {
                        text_mobile.setText("not available");
                    }

                    JSONObject openingObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("opening_hours");
                    open_now = openingObject.optString("open_now", "Not provided");
                    if(resultObject.has("opening_hours")) {
                        if (open_now.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                            open.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            openNow.setText("Open");
                        } else {
                            close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            openNow.setText("Closed");
                        }
                    }else {
                        openNow.setText("no information provided for Open/Close");
                    }



                    if(resultObject.has("photos")){
                        JSONArray photosArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("photos");
                        for (int i = 0; i < photosArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject photosObject = photosArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            img_url = URL_PHOTO + photosObject.optString("photo_reference","No image available") + "&key=" + KEY;

                            if (img_url.isEmpty()) {
                                image_details.setImageResource(R.drawable.hospital);
                            } else {
                                Picasso.with(mContext).load(img_url).fit().centerInside().into(image_details);
                            }

                        }
                    }else{
                        image_details.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_available);
                    }


                    //  mDetailsList.add(new DetailsPojo(img_url));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }


    private void findViewByIds() {
        image_details = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        open = findViewById(R.id.open);
        close = findViewById(R.id.closed);
        text_mobile = findViewById(R.id.text_mobile);
        openNow = findViewById(R.id.text_open_now);
        openingLayout=findViewById(R.id.Openinglayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `JSON` that is coming from the Google APIs https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJoTjQ-EC_wjsRjC-0kVQOIg0&key=AIzaSyBB8VIJUlcVwYC2EnEQATSMIa9S1cDguDg

as you can see in `Logcat` that it is saying that No value for "opening_hours".
& you are trying to get that JSONObject without checking it that it exists or not.

here you can see your code :-

```
JSONObject openingObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("opening_hours");
```

So first validate it that it is coming or not as per the documentation it can even throw the exception if the mapping does not go well.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)